# Is there a relationship between poisson distribution and chi-square distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, chi-squared

I saw the comment on the book that there is a relationship between poisson distribution and chi-square distribution. But the book didn't explain at all. If there is a relationship, what is it?

Comment: it sounds like it is related to Normal distribution - you can relate poisson to normal for large $\lambda$

Comment: A chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom is an exponential distribution with mean 2 and vice versa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationships_among_probability_distributions